# Villager farm getting clogged

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have my villager farm that works almost perfectly.

Two main issues are

- Villagers drowning on the water elevator
- Villagers not walking over the trapdoors

Here are screenshots of the way this works.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The idea is very simple, the little villagers can walk on the open trapdoors and fall down into the riverflow which leads them to the water elevator and they get out in a separate building.

The big villagers cant walk over the trapdoors since they have only 1 block open.

But the villagers dont walk out, even after a few hours they either go into the water and drown or they dont fall at all, they just stay there.

When they reach the escalator the little ones are just sitting in the water on the half-slab and start to drown SOMETIMES. Probably about half of them make it safely.

An old design for a villager farm that I used only had 2 trapdoors and it was almost 99% clog-proof. This one has probably more than 30 and its not working...

I have tried to place the trapdoors against the outside wall but that didnt change anything.

How can I improve the design of this villager farm ?

Comment: Is this an infinite breeder design?  If so, move the "village" towards the direction you want the babies to walk.  It helps with the passive clearing methods.  It's hard to see how the water is setup in the screen shot.  Make sure all water blocks are source blocks in the elevator.  If you have a source at the top and it flows down, it forces mobs to swim upstream.   Pay attention to where the elevator water and the pushing water meet to make sure it always pushes the villagers in the direction you want them to go.

Comment: yes all of the elevator blocks are source blocks, and I have moved the villager with the doors in the direction to help clear them. The elevator itself works as long as the villagers arent trying to walk out of it, and I dont know how to prevent that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two designs that I have used with success.  Use the first one if you need the babies to come out the other end.  They try to walk out of it but if they succeed they get a breath and get pushed back in.  With this design, I always made sure the source block that pushes them into it was close so that it pushed them in with a bit of strength.  If the source block is 7 blocks away, it doesn't push with as much force.

[image: Two Sign]

I use this design now.  It pushes the villagers all the way back into the elevator where they can still breathe.  It is a growing chamber of sorts because they can't exit until they are adults.  If you get a bunch of babies at once, they stack up until they mature and exit.

[image: One sign]

As long as the elevator water are all source blocks, I have them swim ten water blocks before I put a sign so they can catch a breath.  It looks like your system is only three blocks of climb so no air signs would be needed.

---

As to the baby villagers walking out of this design, passive designs always have that flaw.  Babies like to hang out with the adults and some of them will mature in the breed chamber.

---

Here is a completely different village breeder style.

Here is the basic breeder cell:
[image: Breeder Cell]

The villagers are placed into the hole and bounce in the water.  The water is held back on all sides by signs.  When the villagers breed, the babies are pushed out the bottom to be caught and moved.

Here is a shot of a full build with breed cell and baby containment: 
[image: Build]

In this case, the babies are trapped until mature and then they are spit out into the void.

You can see the farmer with his farm in the image.  He has a single hole with a shelf to throw the breeders food.  He keeps them fed, they keep breeding.

[Here is a mediafire download](http://www.mediafire.com/file/d3i0317qmnuiatc/Villager%20Breeder.zip) of that world built for the screenshots.  It is named "Villager Breeder.zip" and it is 250KB.

This world also has a method to disable the village to stop/start breeding as desired.

Comment: Im all ears about that. I'm tired of killing the villagers I can't move out.... I'm interested in a design that works automatically, there are a few ideas I found that require the player to drop food to the villagers manually.

Comment: Give me a little time to build it.   The design I currently use does not require manual feeding of the breeders.  Fully automatic and babies are immediately ejected.  Fairly simple.  I will edit the answer to include the build later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Im looking forward to it brother ;)

Comment: I didnt realise you had changed your answer to provide the villager breeder thats an awesome design - I am going to try to build it soon !

Answer (score 0):

Put a sign every other block in the water elevator, the villagers will still bob up from one water block to the next but they won't drown.

[image]

Comment: My design only has a 3 block elevator... I wouldnt say that is applicable in my case though I will consider it Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Where are your doors located?  I used the same design but had doors under the farm with a “seer” villager who spit the doors.  I also had natural current push the villager baby down to a holding cell where I would come back and check them before letting them run to their cell.

I want to say the seer was something like 6 blocks below.  Best of luck!